# Getting error:`Sending HTTP error code 404: Failed to read stream:null`

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

We are using Jenkins for Maven builds and JFrog artifactory to store our artifacts.
`Jfrog Artifactory version - 5.0.0`
`Jenkins version - 2.7`

The issue we are facing is many times our Jenkins build gets failed due to below error:

> Content-Length: 70410552
>   2017-12-18 18:46:02,286 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-3] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :222) - Sending HTTP error code 404: Failed to read stream: null
>   2017-12-18 18:46:04,388 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom' Content-Length: 10080
>   2017-12-18 18:46:04,455 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-12] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:319) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom.sha1' Content-Length: 40
>   2017-12-18 18:46:04,462 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-15] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:319) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom.md5' Content-Length: 32
>   2017-12-18 18:47:39,021 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-10] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.jar' Content-Length: 70410552
>   2017-12-18 18:47:39,022 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-10] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :222) - Sending HTTP error code 404: Failed to read stream: null
>   2017-12-18 18:47:41,374 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-5] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom' Content-Length: 10080
>   2017-12-18 18:47:41,392 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-2] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:319) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom.sha1' Content-Length: 40
>   2017-12-18 18:47:41,397 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:319) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom.md5' Content-Length: 32
>   2017-12-18 18:49:07,275 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-14] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/bbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.jar' Content-Length: 76484245
>   2017-12-18 18:49:07,276 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-14] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :222) - Sending HTTP error code 404: Failed to read stream: null
>   2017-12-18 18:49:09,431 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-9] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/bbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.pom' Content-Length: 10870
>   2017-12-18 18:49:09,451 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-7] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:319) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/aaaaaa/bbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.pom.sha1' Content-Length: 40

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This was the first line in the artifacroty.log found:

> 2017-12-18 18:46:02,285 [ajp-nio-8019-exec-3] [INFO ] (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:516) - Deploy to 'libs-snapshot-local:com/halodoc/inventory-service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/inventory-service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.jar' Content-Length: 70410552

**Request Log**

> 20171218184602|1|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
>   20171218184602|4|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|778
>   20171218184602|1|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
>   20171218184602|3|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.jar|HTTP/1.1|404|70410552
>   20171218184604|64|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom|HTTP/1.1|201|10080
>   20171218184604|4|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom.sha1|HTTP/1.1|201|40
>   20171218184604|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114602-2.pom.md5|HTTP/1.1|201|32
>   20171218184738|0|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
>   20171218184738|3|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|778
>   20171218184739|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
>   20171218184739|3|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.jar|HTTP/1.1|404|70410552
>   20171218184741|15|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom|HTTP/1.1|201|10080
>   20171218184741|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom.sha1|HTTP/1.1|201|40
>   20171218184741|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/service-1.0.8-20171218.114738-3.pom.md5|HTTP/1.1|201|32
>   20171218184907|0|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
>   20171218184907|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|770
>   20171218184907|1|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
>   20171218184907|2|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.jar|HTTP/1.1|404|76484245
>   20171218184909|17|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.pom|HTTP/1.1|201|10870
>   20171218184909|3|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.pom.sha1|HTTP/1.1|201|40
>   20171218184909|3|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|jenkins|PUT|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/bbbbb/1.0.30-SNAPSHOT/bbbbb-1.0.30-20171218.114907-6.pom.md5|HTTP/1.1|201|32
>   20171218184922|0|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|non_authenticated_user|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|401|0
>   20171218184922|6|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|user-name|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|778
>   20171218184923|1|REQUEST|X.X.X.X|user-name|GET|/libs-snapshot-local/com/aaaa/service/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40

Comment: What do the logs on the Artifactory side say? Especially request.log and artifactory.log?

Comment: @ajeans The above logs are artifactory-logs ^^

Comment: @HussainK This is a snippet of the artifactory.log. There is a missing context. Can you provide the artifactory.log including some time before the error? also, the request.log. Without knowing which request reached Artifactory things are quite obscure. 
(however, if this is an intermittent behaviour, it is most probably a network issue)

Comment: @eranb Posted Request_logs as per your request ^^^